# Jest / Supertest / Node.js - Async/await API call in a loop with multiple tests

Tags: node.js, loops, asynchronous, jestjs, supertest

I have a fairly simple to explain use case which combines the following aspects:

- **Node.js** is my working environment for test development
- Using **Supertest** to call a **remote** API (not an Express app)
- **Jest** to run multiple Describe/It tests
- **Looping** over an array of variables for use in calling the API
- **Async/await** to ensure API call has finished before testing

Some 'pseudo-code' to illustrate the pattern I am attempting:

```
const request = require('supertest')('https://url/api');

const data = [{ "id": 123 }, { "id": 456 }, { "id": 789 }];

const getapi = async function(id) {
    return request
        .get(id)
        .set('Accept', 'application/json')
        .set('Content-Type', 'application/json')
        .set('Authorization', 'removed');
};

var response;

data.forEach(async(item) => {

    describe(`GET ${item.id}`, () => {

        beforeEach(async() => {
            response = await getapi(item.id);
        });

        it('status code is 200', () => {
            expect(response.status).toBe(200)
        });

        it('the id returned is the same as passed in', () => {
            expect(response.body.id).toBe(item.id);
        });

        // ...and so on...

    });

});
```

I expect nicely formatted output for a tester based on Jest's default console reporter, something like:

```
PASS
GET 123
✓ status code is 200
✓ the id returned is the same as passed in
GET 456
...and so on...
```

Instead when I use console.log's I see that each test is called twice for each iteration through the loop. I have searched, read the documentation on each of the modules I am using, and tried a few different approaches for the loop syntax, the await/async, etc. Each time I run into a limitation with one of the above modules that seems to prevent reaching the use case. Is there an alternative approach that I could try?

**Edit:**
Here is a publicly accessible API to test using the same pattern. Console log shows that the API is being called for each individual It() test i.e. 6 times and not 3. To clarify I want to call the API endpoint *once* in each iteration and execute *multiple* tests on each response.

```
const request = require('supertest')('https://api.binance.com/api/v3/avgPrice');

const data = [{ "symbol": "BCHUSDT" }, { "symbol": "ETHUSDT" }, { "symbol": "LTCUSDT" }];

const getapi = async function(symbol) {
    return request
        .get('')
        .query({ symbol: `${symbol}` })
        .set('Accept', 'application/json')
        .set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
};

var response;

data.forEach(async(item) => {

    describe(`GET ${item.symbol}`, () => {

        beforeEach(async() => {
            response = await getapi(item.symbol);
            console.log(response.body);
        });

        it('has a return status code of 200', () => {
            expect(200);
            //console.log(response.body);
        });

        it('has an average price > USD10', () => {
            //console.log(response.body);
            expect(parseInt(response.body.price)).toBeGreaterThan(10);
        });

    });

});
```

Comment: Does anyone out there have experience with it-each and would it help?